# pscustom fill problem 2 times psLorenz

Tags: pstricks

Look at the following MWE which is compiled via `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[gray]{databar}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{pst-plot} 
\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{pst-lens} 
\usepackage{pst-intersect}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 


 \xdefinecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
 \xdefinecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\providecommand{\mytext}{}

\providecommand{\gengini}[6]{%
\newpage%
\FPupn{fra}{#1}%
\pstVerb{/ra \fra\space def}%
\FPupn{frb}{#2}%
\pstVerb{/rb \frb\space def}%
\FPupn{frc}{#3}%
\pstVerb{/rc \frc\space def}%
\FPupn{frd}{#4}%
\pstVerb{/rd \frd\space def}%
\FPupn{fre}{#5}%
\pstVerb{/re \fre\space def}%
\FPupn{frf}{#6}%
\psset{lly=-13mm,llx=-9mm,urx=25mm,ury=15mm}%
\psgraph[xAxisLabel={\ },yAxisLabel={\ },Ox=0,Dx=20,Dy=0.2,dx=0.2](-0.0,-0.0)(1,1){6cm}{6cm}%
 \psclip{%
 \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{%
     \psLorenz[plotstyle=bezier,linecolor=black,liftpen=2]{0.025 0.2 0.21 0.27 0.295}%
     \psLorenz[plotstyle=bezier,linecolor=black,liftpen=2]{ra rb rc rd re}%
     }%
    }%
\endpsclip%
\endpsgraph%
}%


\begin{document}
\gengini{0.00135847}{0.00411338}{0.00163124}{0.00079123}{0.99210568}{1}%   

\end{document}
```

Goal: Fill with color (or other fill-styles) between two `psLorenz` curves. 
Attention: It is required not to subtract areas, because this piece of code is part of other code, too... which is not part of the problem and therefore removed.

I have tried to solve this problem but it seems to me that I am not able to connect the endpoints together.

Update: Goal: Red between both pslorenz. No Fill between lorenz and a simple line

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of what you have and be a bit more specific on your problems. If I compile your MWE, I see a red area between a straight line and a curve. It would be easier if you explain a bit than us having to decipher your source code.

Comment: And please minimize your code. `\usepackage{filecontents}` is unnecessary, to give an example.

Comment: Yes, filecontents was required from a step between to the mwe, because I load datatool in normal operation and load all values from csv files.

All other packages ought to be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\psLorenz` macro uses `\listplot`, and the points of both plots are in the same order (x-values from left to right). In order to fill the area between both curves, you must reverse one of the curves using the `ChangeOrder` parameter provided explicitely for this case of filling between two `\listplot`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}
\psset{lly=-13mm,llx=-9mm,urx=25mm,ury=15mm}%
\psgraph[xAxisLabel={\ },yAxisLabel={\ },Ox=0,Dx=20,Dy=0.2,dx=0.2](-0.0,-0.0)(1,1){6cm}{6cm}%
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{%
  \psLorenz[plotstyle=bezier]{0.025 0.2 0.21 0.27 0.295}
  \psLorenz[plotstyle=bezier, ChangeOrder]{ 0.00135847 0.00411338 0.00163124 0.00079123 0.99210568 1}%
}%
\endpsgraph% 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I generated this png with `pdftocairo -r 100 -png`. When looking at the resulting pdf file with e.g. `okular` I see an artifact line, which I couldn't remove. The following screenshot shows this:

[image]

Alternatively you can use `pst-intersect` to save the first `\psLorenz` curve, and then reverse this path when tracing it with `\pstracecurve`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{pst-intersect}

\begin{document}
\psset{lly=-13mm,llx=-9mm,urx=25mm,ury=15mm}%
\psgraph[xAxisLabel={\ },yAxisLabel={\ },Ox=0,Dx=20,Dy=0.2,dx=0.2](-0.0,-0.0)(1,1){6cm}{6cm}%
  \pssavepath{Lorenz}{\psLorenz[plotstyle=bezier]{0.025 0.2 0.21 0.27 0.295}}
  \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{%
    \pstracecurve[reversepath]{Lorenz}
    \psLorenz[plotstyle=bezier]{ 0.00135847 0.00411338 0.00163124 0.00079123 0.99210568 1}%
  }%
\endpsgraph% 
\end{document}
```

Note, that for this latter solution you need the development version of `pst-intersect` from https://github.com/cbersch/pst-intersect.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell my, why you are going to create a png?
Because if I use pdf only, I dont see this line of example 1.

Comment: I only created the png to show the result here. As I wrote, I do see the additional line with some viewer, with other not: Line appears with okular, Acrobat Reader, gsview. Line does not appear with mupdf, foxit, firefox (pdf.js), chrome (pdfium), pdftocairo.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will once more try the second solution and download the new version of your package. I will wait one or two more days, maybe someone knows the reason for the line...

Answer (score 1):

use two single fills and, of course, do not use the curve style bezier for a Lorenz curve:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}
    \psset{lly=-13mm,llx=-9mm,urx=5mm,ury=5mm}%
    \psgraph[xAxisLabel={},yAxisLabel={},Dx=20,Dy=0.2,
      dx=0.2](0,0)(1,1){6cm}{6cm}%
        \psLorenz*[linecolor=blue!40]{0.025 0.2 0.21 0.27 0.295}
        \kern0.5pt% to get rid of a small vertical rule
        \psLorenz*[linecolor=white,dimen=inner]{ 0.00135847 0.00411338 0.00163124 0.00079123 0.99210568 1}
    \endpsgraph 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the goal is to fill between the to curves, see answer below...

Comment: see my edited answer